# Lambda Expression conversion for a loop to display a list

Tags: c#, list, lambda, functional-programming

I am trying learn the use of lambda expressions and hence still struggling to implement after even reading the documentation and other various related articles on it.
So if I want to convert this following loop into a lambda expression then how would I go about doing it, I just need an approach to look how lambda expressions work.

Code:

```
var pc = Enumerable.Range(2, 100).ToList();
var j = 0;
while (j < pc.Count)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pc[j]);
    j++;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Enumerable.Range(2, 100).ToList().ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p));
```

Step by step explanation

1. Enumerable.Range makes a `IEnumarable<int>` starting from 2 having length 100. ie. items will be 2,3,4.....101.
2. `.ToList()` converts that `IEnumerable` to `List`. Why converting? so that we can use `ForEach` method of `List`.
3. Most Important for you `ForEach()`. As the name suggests it performs action on each item in list. In here each element of list is taken and put in a runtime variable p which 'goes to' `=> Console.WriteLine(p)` to write on console.

Comment: I don't think that it would include 102 (2 to 102 would be 101 elements)

Comment: But is it faster than the normal loop which I write to display the output?

Comment: In your case, performance do not matter as its a simple program. But when there are more lines of code in side LINQ or traditional Loop Traditional loops are faster than LINQ.

Answer (score 3):

I know that's not the answer to your question, but this is an example, where i always reconsider whether LINQ is really the best solution for the problem. I understand that you only need an example for learning, but keep in mind that for a man with a hammer everything looks like a nail...

```
foreach (var item in Enumerable.Range(2, 100))
{
  Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

This is easier for me to understand, and no unnecessary list will be created.

(Hope i get not too many angry comments...)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Enumerable.Range(2, 100).ToList().ForEach(n => Console.WriteLine(n))
```

But please note that in general lambdas are slow due to additional objects being created. Don't use them in performance critical applications.

Comment: So they are slower than the code i provided to display? I just implemented a sieve and then after writing it , saw someone else's on codereview.stackexchange and learned a little bit about lambda expressions and i thought it was a better of implementing it since the code became reasonably concise... So was i wrong in assuming that?

Comment: This example has the advantage, that no list has to be created, it uses the enumeration directly.

Comment: `Enumerable` doesn't have a `.ForEach` method, you need to use `.ToList()` first to use that.

Comment: @Bali C - Upps you are right, one reason to use a foreach loop directly here.

Answer (score 0):

```
pc.ForEach(f => Console.WriteLine(f));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create an in-memory list of the `Enumerable.Range`.

```
var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable.Range(2, total));
Console.Write(result);
```

Comment: While this is a nice solution, the questioneer *wants* to use a lambda expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
pc.ForEach(j => Console.WriteLine(j));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
Enumerable.Range(2, 100).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Enumerable.Range(2, 100).ToList().ForEach(n => Console.WriteLine(n));
```